# Multiselect of items in jQuery Tokeninput

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Tokeninput and I want to allow users to select multiple values from textbox after they chose them from autocomplete, but click on every item clears the previous selection.

[image]

I tried to override by catching the click of token-input-token-facebook class but that doesn't work for me. The solution can be overriding as well as removing the existing click functionality.

Thnx for the assistance

Comment: why a user want to select again and again (after autocomplete select that should be our final select) and for one's which are not required can be cleared by using cross icon.

Comment: well, we have some tricky functionality based on combinations. the user may check suggestions for specific keyword groups, so he can choose 3 of them for example and see the results for specific group.

Comment: @Boltosaurus Could you solve the issue. I also trying to implement a multiselect in the suggest list.